# Rails: find attachments without user OR without comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Attachment `has_one :comment, optional: true`

Attachment `has_one :user, through :comment`, comment - through task, task - through project

I want to find all current_user attachments plus attachments without owner -> no parent comment

Query `Attachment.joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where('projects.user_id = ? OR attachments.comment_id IS NULL', user.id)` doesnt include attachments without comment, why?

```
[10] pry(#<CommentResource>)> Attachment.all
=> [#<Attachment:0x00000008a6f3a8
  id: 1,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Attachment:0x00000008a6f268
  id: 2,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Attachment:0x00000008a6f128
  id: 3,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: nil,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:29:51 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:29:51 UTC +00:00>]
[11] pry(#<CommentResource>)> Attachment.joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where('projects.user_id = ? OR attachments.comment_id IS NULL', user.id).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"attachments\".* FROM \"attachments\" INNER JOIN \"comments\" ON \"comments\".\"id\" = \"attachments\".\"comment_id\" INNER JOIN \"tasks\" ON \"tasks\".\"id\" = \"comments\".\"task_id\" INNER JOIN \"projects\" ON \"projects\".\"id\" = \"tasks\".\"project_id\" WHERE (projects.user_id = 1 OR attachments.comment_id IS NULL)"
[12] pry(#<CommentResource>)> Attachment.joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where('projects.user_id = ? OR attachments.comment_id IS NULL', user.id)
=> [#<Attachment:0x0000000891c7a8
  id: 1,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Attachment:0x0000000891c668
  id: 2,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joins method on active record queries the records by using inner join, which means in your case it only returns attachments with comments. If you want to include attachments without comments, you need to left outer join.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. `Attachment.left_outer_joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where('projects.user_id = ? OR comment_id IS NULL', user.id)`